# What rare elements would be most needed in building a space station beyond the Earth?

Tags: science-based, chemistry, space-constructs

If people were attempting to build a space station beyond the [Hill Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere), (outside of the area where Earth's gravity dominates), and wanted to mine the raw materials for the station from dwarf planets, comets, and asteroids, what rare earth element or mineral would they mostly likely be looking for to building and/or maintaining the station?

Comment: Given the chemistry tag, that would seem to be the case.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen To be fair, I did not originally include the chemistry tag.

Answer (score 6):

No matter how you build the station, if you lack oxygen there is no way you can inhabit it.

Since oxygen is also an important constituent of water, and water is essential to life, this doubles its importance.

Without inhabitants you cannot maintain the space station.

Comment: That would have been my answer, too. Though if the space station is manned by robots, that might not be the case.

Comment: This.  Oxygen, nitrogen, etc. to allow a large empty space to actually become a breathable atmosphere

Answer (score 4):

**Gold**

The most important contributor to the successful completion of any complex venture is whatever motivates those who have the resources and skills to get the job done.

Money has thus far proven to be a very effective motivator!

Comment: Strictly speaking money are made also of paper, plastic, seashells...

Comment: In a post-scarcity economy, money need not be a factor, and the drive to explore and expand would be the main motivator.

Comment: @L.Dutch, my favourite is the rai stones, 4 ton coins that can't be moved

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen, be careful wishing for a post-scarcity economy.  All paths from where we are now to such a theoretical utopia are bloody.  Our current economic methods are not evil.  They have been misused to produce an unwise disparity in the distribution of wealth, but fundamentally having a method to barter different skills and resources is a good thing.  Even in our age of scarcity, our drive is to explore and expand.  Money simply focuses that drive upon single goal rather than having it disperse ineffectively in multiple directions at once.

Comment: @L.Dutch and Separatrix, strickly speaking, paper, plastic seashells and maybe even rai stones are not made out of a single element.  I could have used silver or even platinum, but gold works for this question.